QGIS Model Designer: Different outputs on different devices
I have a very weird problem with QGIS Model Designer, The model (.model3) file was producing correct results up until yesterday but today onwards that model is not providing the correct output. I haven't made any changes in the model but I was working on a python export of it. Since this model was a part of the evolution that I have made in the past few months, one of the model that I had as a backup was working fine and hence I made changes in it and now it's producing the desired output wherein I have duplicated all the changes that were present in my current model.
But another weird thing is happening, once I share this with my colleagues they are getting different results for the same data and model. Any specific reason as to why this is occurring? Am I missing out on something wrt model designer? I am using QGIS 3.34.9, my peers are using 3.34.8 or 3.32 version.

The model is actually producing different results for me as well on starting different instance of qgis
